# CSS selector :last-of-type not behaving as expected

Tags: css

Why doe the last div.form-form-element-wrapper have a bottom border? I thought that the :last-of-type selector would remove the border.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqnbu

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>details</legend>
    <div class="form-form-element-wrapper">
      <div>
        <div> 
          <label>Name</label>
       </div>
       <div> 
         <input type="text" maxlength="128" value="dsf sdf sdafs">
      </div>
      <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-form-element-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div> 
      <label>Bank</label>
    </div>
    <div> 
      <select>
        <option value="" selected="selected">---Please select a bank---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  <div class="form-error"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-form-element-wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="form-label"> <label>Length</label>
  </div>
<div> 
  <select>---Please select period---</option>
  </select>
</div>
  <div class="form-error"></div></div>
</div>
  <div class="form-markup-wrapper">
  <p class="bold">Make </p>
  </div>
</fieldset>

.form-form-element-wrapper {
  border-bottom: 5px solid gold; 
  position: relative;
}
.form-form-element-wrapper:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none ;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is simply that `:last-of-type` deals with the type of the *element*, and disregards the class-name/attributes of that elements.

Comment: @DavidThomas is correct. The `:last-of-type` selector references elements not classes. Here is the proper syntax `element:last-of-type { style properties }` from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with `:last-of-type` if you keep this HTML structure.

If you have made fallbacks, you could use `nth-child`, but that is `CSS3` and not supported by a couple of browser(s) versions, so not optimal.

As *@David Thomas* said: the `:last-of-type` does not deal with the class name or attributes of these elements, but the element itself. You have a `fieldset` in which you have placed 4 divs and you are trying to remove the border of the last one, but that is actually not the last one, but the third one... it would have worked if you had three divs in the fieldset and used it like this:

`fieldset div:last-of-type {  border-bottom: none; }`, but that is not the case now.

**You have two options: change your HTML structure or use CSS3.**

Comment: `last-of-child`...doesn't exist AFAIK. Do you mean `last-child`? Also,  `fieldset div:last-child` would target very div that was the last child nested in a field-set. Probably NOT what is intended, given the structure.

Comment: Edited it. It was a typo, I meant type.

Comment: Equally, `last-of type` refers to the last of type within a parent. So, again, perhaps not what is required. Nice thinking though.